# Install libuv on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libuv

I am trying to build cpp-driver from Datastax website. I am on ubuntu 12.04. In the instructions it is written to add ppa:linuxjedi/ppa to the repository so that libuv can be installed. However i am getting

```
Package libuv-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libuv-dev' has no installation candidate
```

when i try to do an update after adding the ppa. Is there an alternative to installing libuv on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try building from source:

```
sudo apt-get install make automake libtool curl
curl -sSL https://github.com/libuv/libuv/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz | sudo tar zxfv - -C /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/libuv-1.8.0
sudo sh autogen.sh
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/src/libuv-1.8.0 && cd ~/
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the PPA with -E option :

`sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:linuxjedi/ppa
sudo apt-get update`

and then run

`sudo apt-get install g++ make cmake libuv-dev libssl-dev`